# Delete an item from array preserving indexes

Tags: arrays, ruby

There is an array of objects, many of which appear in the array several times. There is an index to a specific location of one item. I want to delete one object from the array at all locations, while maintaining the index. An index to the deleted item should move to the next available item, and if there is none then it should wrap back around to the beginning of the array.

I don't think I'm explaining it very well, so here's a simple example:

```
array = [:b, :a, :b]
index = 2
```

Now delete `:a` from the array, and the index should now be 1, since the second `:b` is now at index 1.

Let's say an index points to the deleted object, it should move to the next available object. So if indexes had been 1 it would not change since it would now point to `:b` which immediately followed `:a`.

Here's a wraparound example:

```
array = [:b, :a]
index = 1
```

If you delete `:a` then the index should wrap around to the next available index, or 0.

Seems simple, but there are much more complicated edge cases. Here's the most complex example I could think of:

```
array = [:a, :a, :b, :a, :c, :b, :a]
```

After deleting ':a', the resulting array is `[:b, :c, :b]`. From all possible starting indexes (0 to 6) they should change to 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0.

Assume there is more than one object in the array, so it never becomes empty after deletion.

(Edit)

Thanks to @Raffael for informing me that I should include what I've tried so far. Here was my first attempt:

- `@items` is the array.
- `@current_item_index` is the index that needs to be adjusted.
- `item` is the item being deleted.

The code:

```
indexes = @items.each_index.each_with_object([]) do |i, memo|
  memo << i if @items[i] == item
end

indexes.reverse.each do |i|
  @items.delete_at(i)
  @current_item_index -= 1 if i < @current_item_index
  @current_item_index = 0 unless @current_item_index < @items.size
end
```

It just didn't seem very "Ruby" (not clear nor concise). Also doesn't seem very performant, as it runs through the list twice -- not to mention all those `delete_at` calls which can't be good.

Comment: Why are you doing this, i.e., what's the use context?  Might there not be a better way to achieve your end goal?

Comment: You asked this question more than 40 minutes ago. There are no answers and just one comment. That means nobody understands your question. In your first example, you delete `:a`, which is at index 1, even though `index =  2`. What is the rule that leads you to do that? I thought maybe you were deleting the element at `index - 1`. In the second example, however, when `index = 1` I expected `:b` to be deleted, since it is at index `index - 1 #=> 0`, but no, it's `:a` , which is at index 1, that's deleted. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @pjs: I have a list of players in a game, with an index that keeps track of the current player. Players may have multiple turns, so they're in the array multiple times. This algorithm is intended to be run when a player exits the game. I'm completely open to refactoring the representation if a better one is presented.

Comment: Technically, for this to be a well posed question you should show what you tried so far. I prefer helping you over doing your job. But hey, I'm up for a riddle :)

Comment: You have remarked about weakness of the code you posted, but are silent on the most important point: does it work? If it does, that should allow readers to figure out the question if they can't otherwise. I suggest you edit to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new index is equal to the number of elements in the old array that

- are placed in front of the old index
- will remain in the array

You can count these on the go while constructing the new array like so:

```
def delete_and_follow(old_array, old_index, unwanted)
  new_array, new_index = [], 0
  old_array.each.with_index do |item, idx|
    unless item == unwanted
      new_array << item
      new_index += 1 if idx < old_index
    end
  end
  new_index = 0 if new_index >= new_array.length
  [new_array, new_index]
end
```

Or do the same with less code (though a bit more cryptic):

```
def delete_and_follow(old_array, old_index, unwanted)
  new_index = old_array.take(old_index).count{ |item| item != unwanted }
  new_array = old_array - [unwanted]
  [new_array, new_index % new_array.length]
end
```

HTH!

Comment: Note that this does not modify the `old_array` in-place. Let me know if you prefer in-place.

Comment: This looks good. I just replaced the old array and index when done. My original attempt was in-place and it looked pretty ugly.